# Unable to embed a youtuve videos inside my asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube

I have installed the `Microsoft.Windows.Helpers` reference, and i wrote the following inside my view:

```
@Video.Flash(path:"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5k-mqaaT5RQ&list=UUCd6RY4fxnRbI7VGeg5rajA&index=1",
width:"400",
height:"600",
play:true,
loop:true,
menu: false,
quality: "medium",
scale: "exactfit",
windowMode: "transparent")
```

But when I open the view the page keeps loading for a while then no videos is displayed, so what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Would you not be better off iframing your video since the video isn't stored locally on your site?

I've only ever used the `@Video.Flash(path: /media/videoname.swf)` when I have the video stored locally on my hosting site.

```
<iframe width="400" 
        height="600" 
        src="  NEED YOUR EMBED TAG HERE" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can find more information http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/files,-images,-and-media/10-working-with-video

Answer (score 1):

Path to the video should be in format `youtube.com/v/{id}`, not `youtube.com/watch?v={id}` So try

```
@Video.Flash(path:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/5k-mqaaT5RQ&list=UUCd6RY4fxnRbI7VGeg5rajA&index=1",
width:"400",
height:"600",
play:true,
loop:true,
menu: false,
quality: "medium",
scale: "exactfit",
windowMode: "transparent")
```